# What is the difference between "Ignore" and "Disabled" of network setup during RHEL 9 installation?

Tags: redhat, ipv6, rhel9

I am setting up RHEL 9 server and want to disable IPv6 because my network does not support IPv6 routing.
When setting up connection, I have 2 options "Ignore" or "Disabled" and wondering what the difference is.

Here's the screenshot.

[RHEL 9 connection setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miJI9.png)

Could you explain the difference so that I can choose the proper one?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Does [Why does the interface have an IPv6 address with IPv6 disabled?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/569689/266568) answer your question?

Comment: I am sorry for the late response, I did not notice your comment. Thank you very much! It helped me a lot :)